# How to improve Pytesseract results by preprocessing document images using OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I have docs images and I want to extract the text by py-tesseract
I'm trying to apply some document image enhancements using OpenCV
But the results were not good at all, especially the numbers on the right-hand side
[image: My image]

```
path = '1.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(path)
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=1.8, fy=1.8, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
text= str(pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang='eng', config='--psm 4 -c preserve_interword_spaces=1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist= 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ* ' ))
print(text)
```

My results

> ALBERTVILLE—Marshall County
> SAND MOUNTAIN INFIRMARY Est 1929—200 S Bro d St—T        i
> AN OM Ae7.8--FeL-2-4-7- 11-13-20               a      el 44—Trudie C. Bohannon,   32 | OI    25 2028 20 8 357 3 $122 $54 35 —
> ALEXANDER CITY—Tallapoosa County
> RUSSELL Est 1923—Lee St—Tel Adams 4-343 I1—J      W.                _
>
> 2469-11. 13-20    ,                   ames    Brown Jr., Adm.—A-7-8—F-|-2-   33 | |    55 2316 31 %I5 548 5    _—    wes OP wee
> ANDALUSIA—Covington County
> COVINGTON MEMORIAL Est 1941—106 E Wat   St—
>
> See 34 6-911 -13-20               atson    Tel 305—G. H. Stanley, Adm.—   32 | OI    40 2392 25 10 378 3   164    8 43 —
> HILLCREST INFIRMARY Est 1943—200 Hil     _    as
>
> More A.T-8—F-2I            ilicrest Dr—Te! 800—Kathryne Farmer, Bus.  33 | #4   85 1238  26 15 100  l  198  88  46  —
> ANNISTON—Calhoun County
> ANNISTON MEMORIAL Est 1944—400 E [0th St Box 390—         -542|—
>
> Weizel Adm A-7-8—-F-1-2-3-4-6-9-10-1 1-13-14-15-16-20   Tel Adams 7-542|—Harold E.    41 |   159 8306 II7) 24 1912 18 936 576 267   i)

I'm trying to enhance a document image with OpenCV to get good results from pytesseract thank you

Comment: Your image has excellent quality, high contrast, perfectly clean background. There is nothing you v-can gain by preprocessing. You could help Tesseract by splitting the rows yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
Did you mean to use the contour to divide the rows row by row and then
feed results to Tesseract?
Will this improve the results

Comment: Any method, but one line at a time. This will only improve the order, not the recognition.

Comment: try a different psm configuration

Comment: thank you for answering, I tried this but got the best results from psm 4

Comment: i can suggest [easyocr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76846836/tesseract-ocr-not-being-able-to-read-two-rows-of-text-on-red-background/76846879#76846879) again.

Comment: thank you @YunusTemurlenk I'm not familiar with EasyOCR, is it easy to use with large documents, I've read some articles about it, can you give me an example of its application on document images?
thanks for your help

Comment: @MKROSTM i tried in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcTSi0ZREDA) with some document kind of texts also, usage is simple. I prefer mostly eascyocr in my projects. but of course tesseract is more adjustable for document texts

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk, thank you, I watched the video and it seems easy to use and good in text extraction, I think needs a lot of manipulations when working with large doc text